# Riesz's 1909 proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, math-history, riesz-representation-theorem

Frigyes Riesz originally proved the Riesz Representation Theorem on $ C[0,1] $ -- [here](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/riesz-operations-fonctionnelles-lineaires) is his 1909 paper in English ([original French](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/sites/default/files/pdf/Riesz-Operations-Fonctionnelles-Lineaires-1909.pdf)). He builds a real valued function $ \text{A} $ on $ [0,1] $ satisfying

$$ {{\LARGE{\sum_i}} {{\left|\text{A}(x_i)-2\text{A}\left({{x_i+x_{i+1}}\over 2}\right)+\text{A}(x_{i+1})\right|} \over {x_{i+1}-x_i}}} \leq {M_{\mathcal{A}} \over 2} $$

for any partition $ \{0=x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots x_{n-1} = 1\} $ and a fixed constant $ M_{\mathcal{A}} $, then says, "It follows that the derived numbers of the function $ \text{A}(x) $ exist and that these derivatives are functions of bounded variation."

> **My problem:** By "derived numbers" he means the Dini derivative (upper right, say). Granted the expression in the sum is close to a difference quotient, I'm still not seeing why the upper right Dini derivative exists and is of bounded variation.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Riesz's 1909 paper cited above announced the Riesz Representation Theorem in a brief note. He gave more details in a [followup paper in 1911](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/rieszs-equations-integrales). There he rewites the sum above as:

$${{\LARGE{\sum_{\large{k=1}}^{\large{m-1}}}} \left|{{\text{A}(x_{k+1}) - \text{A}(x_k)} \over {x_{k+1}-x_k}} - {{\text{A}(x_k) - \text{A}(x_{k-1})} \over {x_k-x_{k-1}}} \right|} \leq G,$$

where $x_k$ is the midpoint. Putting $D_k = \large{{\text{A}(x_k)-\text{A}(x_{k-1})} \over {x_k-x_{k-1}}}$, this reads:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} |D_{k+1} - D_k| \leq G,$$

which makes it clear that the difference quotients are of bounded variation, hence bounded, so $\text{A}$ has finite upper Dini derivatives.

I wrote up the recapituation here: [Riesz Proves the Riesz Representation Theorem](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/riesz-proves-riesz-representation-theorem). His proof was highly concrete, based on simple piecewise linear functions on $[0,1]$ — easy to understand and a real work of art.

Comment: HINt: If the function ($A(X_k)$ ??) is increasing then the upper right Dini is bounded $D^+<\infty$, (the upper right Dini .)

Comment: On your page http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/reading-eulers-introductio-analysin-infinitorum there is a bad typo: a few lines below equation (13) it says $\zeta(2) = \pi/6$.

Comment: Arghhh! Fixed now. Thanks very much.